# Somebody please help - Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia and a fujitsu lifebook ah544

Tags: nvidia

For the life of me I can never get graphics working on my Lifebook. Using Nvidia current means that X never starts.

NVIDIA GeForce GT720M with 2GB Dedicated Video Memory (Optional)
Intel HD Graphics 4600

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Terribly sorry for the threadnomancy, but after following the link I now cannot get X at all. I've been trying to sort this out on my own with no luck. I'm posting this using a Ubuntu Live usb stick. The errors I get are related to Fatal Error No screens found and undefined screen nvidia

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my GTX970 running on 14.10 with the help of [this fine site](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/nvidia-343-22-install-in-ubuntu-1404/)

---

The easiest and cleanest way to do this is to get it from the xorg-edgers PPA

You will want to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

NOTE: These packages are updated frequently and sometimes certain builds disappear so if your install command doesn't pull through you will want to go to the PPA on launchpad:
https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Generally just look for the newest number unless you know exactly what your looking for.

Now rejoice in the glory of your functional video card!