# Cursor and Wallpaper only

Tags: 14.04, gnome, nvidia, xorg

after following the instructions on my previous question here [Somebody please help - Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia and a fujitsu lifebook ah544](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594780/somebody-please-help-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-and-a-fujitsu-lifebook-ah544) I'm now stuck with the old problem of only showing wallpaper and mouse cursor.

I have tried various solutions from Askubuntu and various Googling but I'm no further on.

From the link suggested below that hasn't helped either.

Thanks in advance for any help at all

Update: I'm using Gnome, and have made sure that I have the correct drivers for the graphics card using instructions from here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Xsession here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10738904/

Xorg

```
[   660.170] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[   660.170] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   660.170] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   660.170] Current Operating System: Linux alan-LIFEBOOK-AH544 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64
[   660.170] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=9b2d8c33-495a-46d1-b315-0533018cb2bf ro i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   660.170] Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
[   660.171] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   660.171] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[   660.171]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   660.171] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   660.171] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr  3 22:06:10 2015
[   660.171] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   660.171] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   660.171] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   660.171] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   660.171] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   660.171] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   660.171] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   660.171] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   660.171] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   660.171] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   660.171]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   660.171] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   660.171]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   660.171] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   660.171]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   660.171] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   660.171]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   660.171] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   660.171]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   660.171] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   660.171] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   660.171] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   660.171] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f55133b9d40
[   660.171] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   660.171]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   660.171]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[   660.171]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[   660.171]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[   660.171] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   660.173] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:10cf:17a9 rev 6, Mem @ 0xf1000000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension Present
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   660.173] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   660.173] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[   660.173] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   660.173] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[   660.173] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   660.174] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[   660.174] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so: libnvidia-tls.so.331.113: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[   660.174] (II) UnloadModule: "glx"
[   660.174] (II) Unloading glx
[   660.174] (EE) Failed to load module "glx" (loader failed, 7)
[   660.174] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[   660.174] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[   660.174] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[   660.174] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[   660.174] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[   660.174] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   660.174] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   660.174] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   660.174] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   660.174]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.917
[   660.174]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   660.174]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   660.174] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   660.175] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   660.175] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   660.175]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[   660.175]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   660.175]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   660.175] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   660.175] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   660.175] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   660.175]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[   660.175]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   660.175]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   660.175] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   660.175] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   660.175] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   660.175]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[   660.175]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   660.175]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   660.175] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   660.175] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[   660.175] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[   660.175] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[   660.175] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   660.175] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   660.175] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   660.175] (++) using VT number 7

[   660.180] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20080730
[   660.180] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20150318.bacaf7f1-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty (Robert Hooker <sarvatt@ubuntu.com>)
[   660.180] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[   660.180] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   660.181] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   660.181] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   660.181] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   660.181] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   660.181] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   660.181]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[   660.181]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   660.181] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   660.181] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
[   660.181] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2; using a maximum of 2 threads
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   660.181] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   660.181] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[   660.181] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[   660.181] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface acpi_video0 (type 'firmware') for output eDP1
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[   660.181] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[   660.181] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[   660.181] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 1366x768 on pipe 0
[   660.182] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[   660.182] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   660.182] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   660.182] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   660.182] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   660.182] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[   660.182] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[   660.182] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module present
[   660.182] (II) UnloadModule: "present"
[   660.182] (II) Unloading present
[   660.182] (EE) intel: Failed to load module "present" (module does not exist, 0)
[   660.182] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   660.182] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   660.182] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   660.182] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   660.182] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   660.182] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[   660.182] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   660.182] (II) Unloading vesa
[   660.182] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   660.182] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Haswell (gen7.5, gt2) backend
[   660.182] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[   660.182] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   660.182] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[   660.182] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[   660.182] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[   660.183] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[   660.183] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   660.183] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[   660.183] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[   660.183] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[   660.183] (--) RandR disabled
[   660.188] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   660.191] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[   660.191] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[   660.198] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   660.200] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   660.200] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.200] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[   660.201] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   660.201] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   660.201]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.8.2
[   660.201]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   660.201]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[   660.201] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   660.201] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   660.201] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[   660.201] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   660.201] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   660.201] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.201] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[   660.201] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   660.201] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.201] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.201] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.203] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2B4266AA55228AE7D9557A18F1965DBA19850816.xkm
[   660.203] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Fujitsu FUJ02E3 (/dev/input/event7)
[   660.203] (**) Fujitsu FUJ02E3: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.203] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Fujitsu FUJ02E3'
[   660.204] (**) Fujitsu FUJ02E3: always reports core events
[   660.204] (**) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02E3: Device: "/dev/input/event7"
[   660.204] (--) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02E3: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[   660.204] (--) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02E3: Found keys
[   660.204] (II) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02E3: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.204] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/FUJ02E3:00/input/input8/event7"
[   660.204] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Fujitsu FUJ02E3" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   660.204] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.204] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.204] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.204] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event10)
[   660.204] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.204] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[   660.204] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   660.204] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event10"
[   660.204] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[   660.204] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[   660.204] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.204] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input11/event10"
[   660.204] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   660.204] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.204] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.204] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.204] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Fujitsu FUJ02B1 (/dev/input/event6)
[   660.204] (**) Fujitsu FUJ02B1: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.204] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Fujitsu FUJ02B1'
[   660.204] (**) Fujitsu FUJ02B1: always reports core events
[   660.204] (**) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02B1: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[   660.204] (--) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02B1: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[   660.204] (--) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02B1: Found keys
[   660.204] (II) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02B1: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.204] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/FUJ02B1:00/input/input7/event6"
[   660.205] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Fujitsu FUJ02B1" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.205] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event9)
[   660.205] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.205] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[   660.205] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   660.205] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event9"
[   660.205] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[   660.205] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[   660.205] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.205] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3c/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10/event9"
[   660.205] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.205] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   660.205] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.205] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   660.205] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   660.205] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[   660.205] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   660.205] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   660.205] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.205] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[   660.205] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.205] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.206] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[   660.206] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   660.206] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   660.206] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0) card0 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[   660.206] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   660.206] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event15)
[   660.206] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   660.206] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   660.206] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[   660.206] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   660.206] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   660.206] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[   660.206] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   660.206] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   660.207] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OpticalWheel Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
[   660.207] (**) USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   660.207] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB OpticalWheel Mouse'
[   660.207] (**) USB OpticalWheel Mouse: always reports core events
[   660.207] (**) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[   660.207] (--) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Vendor 0x4fc Product 0x3
[   660.207] (--) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[   660.207] (--) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[   660.207] (--) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Found relative axes
[   660.207] (--) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[   660.207] (II) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[   660.207] (II) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[   660.207] (**) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   660.207] (**) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   660.207] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input6/event4"
[   660.207] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB OpticalWheel Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[   660.207] (II) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[   660.207] (**) USB OpticalWheel Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   660.207] (**) USB OpticalWheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   660.207] (**) USB OpticalWheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   660.207] (**) USB OpticalWheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   660.207] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB OpticalWheel Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   660.207] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   660.207] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   660.207] (II) config/udev: Adding input device FJ Camera (/dev/input/event8)
[   660.207] (**) FJ Camera: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.207] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'FJ Camera'
[   660.207] (**) FJ Camera: always reports core events
[   660.208] (**) evdev: FJ Camera: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[   660.208] (--) evdev: FJ Camera: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0xb413
[   660.208] (--) evdev: FJ Camera: Found keys
[   660.208] (II) evdev: FJ Camera: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.208] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input9/event8"
[   660.208] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "FJ Camera" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[   660.208] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.208] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.208] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.208] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event12)
[   660.208] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   660.208] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   660.208] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[   660.208] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   660.208] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   660.208] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[   660.208] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   660.208] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   660.208] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   660.208] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[   660.208] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[   660.208] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[   660.208] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[   660.208] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[   660.208] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[   660.208] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   660.208] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   660.208] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   660.209] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event5)
[   660.209] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[   660.209] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[   660.209] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[   660.209] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[   660.209] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[   660.209] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   660.209]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.7.4
[   660.209]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   660.209]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[   660.209] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[   660.209] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[   660.209] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[   660.240] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: found clickpad property
[   660.240] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1472 - 5654 (res 40)
[   660.240] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1408 - 4678 (res 51)
[   660.240] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[   660.240] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[   660.240] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left double triple
[   660.240] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[   660.240] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[   660.240] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[   660.240] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[   660.256] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event5"
[   660.256] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 15)
[   660.256] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[   660.256] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[   660.256] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.038
[   660.256] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   660.256] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[   660.256] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   660.256] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   660.256] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[   660.256] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   660.256] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[   660.773] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 13890
[   660.773] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   660.774] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: FJ Camera: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: USB OpticalWheel Mouse: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02B1: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: Fujitsu FUJ02E3: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.328] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[   733.328] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.331] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

lspci Results

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core     Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
```

Comment: What's your desktop environment? Unity, Gnome Shell, or something else?

Comment: I'm using Gnome.

Comment: Thanks. That makes an important difference, because the solution will look different than for Unity.

Comment: You could try [Gnome-session broken for specific account, works for other accounts](/q/576586/175814). Otherwise, please post your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: Sadly no joy with that.

Comment: Can we have `~/.xsession-errors` too please?

Comment: When I tried last night I ran out of characters, I'll delete something out of that Xorg log and try again later

Comment: @AlanShaw Instead you can upload the second log to http://paste.ubuntu.com and then provide the link in your post.

Comment: Link added above cheers all

Comment: Do you have dual graphics Intel and Nvidia or just Nvidia? If you don't know please [edit] your question to include `lspci -nn | grep VGA`.

Comment: @seth Dual graphics

Comment: Is this dead then? No further ideas from anyone?

Answer (score -1):

I think something similar happened to me, some group of commands solved it, and I remember `setsid unity`, so try the following:

[How do I restart Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31849/how-do-i-restart-unity)

---

I think these were the commands (not sure):

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
unity --reset-icons
```

If you can't open terminal, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or +<kbd>F2</kbd>...<kbd>F6</kbd>), to switch to a different TTY (1-6), and log into your account. Your graphical surface is on TTY7 (+<kbd>F7</kbd>).
Probably you have to do `sudo su` before entering those commands...

post the outcome ;)

Comment: There is no /org/compiz on my system only a /org/gnome

Comment: This doesn't work for Gnome Desktop.